# Table sidebars move down

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a website, which is being built in tables, since I'm not very good with CSS yet.
Got this table structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Siderbar 1</td>
    <td>Main Part</td>
    <td>Sidebar 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that once my "Main Part" expands down, the sidebars moves down with it, allways trying to be in the middle.

Is there a way I can make them stay at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<td valign="top">` to make your sidebar always in top like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Siderbar 1</td>
    <td>Main Part</td>
    <td valign="top">Sidebar 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and if your sidebar content can be more than main part, then you can also add  `<td valign="top">` to Main Part.

Comment: If you really want to help a user that explicit express not being good at CSS, show them how-to with an external CSS sample and not old inline style/attribute, which is a really bad way for styling.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use tables for layout**

Tables are for tabular data only. A better solution than using `valign` would be to create your layout using `div` elements and CSS styles.

Read the following article for reasons not to use tables for modern web design (ie. post 1995):

http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Comment: You can also do a search on "CSS layout tutorial" or something similar.

Comment: If you had read the entire post, you whould have known, as I said in the beginning that I'm not very familier with CSS and divs, and is still learning

Yes, I know that divs would have been a better solution, but my current skill set does not stretch to this point, and I was running a bit low on time to learn it, and re-code the entier layout

Comment: @PeaceDealer I had read the entire post, and I hope you've only taken this as constructive criticism. I am just recommending that rather than spending time finding solutions for table layout, I would invest that time looking into div/css layout. This would also make your alignment issue irrelevant

Comment: If you are not gonna show a sample within your answer, at least use SO posts as a reference, as the chance they will be deleted when internally linked is more or less zero., which is not the case for external content. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822650/creating-a-sidebar-within-a-flexbox-with-css

Answer (score 0):

First it is a bad practice to design layout with tables. Please read the curt specified link.
Generally the content in the `<td>` is middle align and if one cell in the row has more content then automatically all other cells in that row will expands. so in the layout unnecessary white spaces will shown.
valign property is deprecated so if you want the content on top use the CSS property

```
vertical-align:top
```